# block diagram model for elevator FSM

Tags: state-machines

I have tried to design the block diagram for an elevator FSM as outlined by the steps provided by Mikef in this Stack Exchange post: [SystemVerilog Elevator FSM issues with conceptual design and translation to code](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/588335/systemverilog-elevator-fsm-issues-with-conceptual-design-and-translation-to-code)

[image]

After many iterations of trying to wrap my head around the converting the statements to hardware, I came up with this block diagram. Am I correct in having RS flip flops to control the incoming elevator requests? And does it make a difference if I embed the registers that store elevator outputs (like motor on/direction, etc.) inside the state machine rather than on the output?

Also, is there anything from a design perspective that looks wrong and jumps out? Please let me know. Thank you, I am a beginner and trying to become a better digital designer.

Can I do without the input registers and muxes?

[image]

Comment: The fsm contains the registers. Without the storage of state you don’t have a state machine! All you would have is combinatorial logic. Yes, you could embed the state of the inputs and definitely the state of the outputs in your fsm.

Comment: Do I need the registers in between the RS flip flops and state machine?

Comment: And now I'm wondering if I even need those multiplexors to sample the input when I can just read them in from the registers or in the case that I scrap, them, then just the RS flip flops?

Comment: The finite state machine consists of a block of combinatorial logic that has inputs from your pushbuttons etc and feedback from the output registers. You need enough output registers to store your current state. The design process is draw your state diagram, derive your state encoding to determine how many bits of state you need then draw up the state table. All pencil and paper stuff. As a 13yo I was taught this, so its not difficult. Now i just write some verilog and it does the grunt work.

Comment: Yeah I get how a state machine works, it's more the datapath and surrounding logic that I've been trying to understand

Comment: There is no reason why all the logic could be in the fsm. How many bits do you require to represent your he state?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2vyQG5k

Comment: Don't forget an input which forces the motor "off" (safety). It is not necessary the reset. Have you inputs that you are at the right stage ?